# GitExtensions - OpenSSH ignores ~/.ssh/config file

Tags: openssh, git-extensions

Using gitextensions I try to clone my remote repository which results in gitextensions running the following command

```
> C:\cygwin\bin\git.exe clone -v --recurse-submodules --progress "gitbox:/projects/testing.git" "C:/Users/craig/MyCode/Personal/testing"
```

which fails with

> Permission denied (publickey).

However if I run the exact same command from a cygwin bash shell it succeeds. So in addition to a standard configuration I also have a ~/.ssh/config which sets up the 'gitbox' alias for ease of use.

My ~/.ssh/config file looks like this

```
# My GitBox - 
Host gitbox
  Hostname mydomain.com
  User git
  IdentityFile /home/craig/.ssh/craig@home
  Port 2022 # i.e non-standard port
```

In GitExtensions I have the OpenSSH option checked, and I also have HOME set to where my cygwin installation is, and more specifically where the user account ie c:/cygwin/home/craig

My conclusion is that somehow the ~/.ssh/config file is not being read and utilised. Everything I can find indicates that an incorrect HOME directory in gitextensions would be the problem but I can't see what's up with my setup.

Thanks in advance

Craig

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GitExtensions by default set HOME variable to "C:\Users\". You can change this in settings dialog.